# If "futures do nothing unless awaited", why does `tokio::spawn` work anyway?

Tags: rust, async-await, future, rust-tokio

I have read [here](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/04_async_await_primer.html) that futures in Rust do nothing unless they are awaited. However, I tried a more complex example and it is a little unclear why I get a message printed by the 2nd print [in this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5102cfd397fd8d417f0018dde6b43cc8) because `task::spawn` gives me a `JoinHanlde` on which I do not do any `.await`.

Meanwhile, I tried the [same example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c51332210337ffdf633502f90d4d44e2), but with an await above the 2nd print, and now I get printed only the message in the 1st print.

If I wait for all the futures at the end, I get printed both messages, which I understood. My question is why the behaviour in the previous 2 cases.

```
use futures::stream::{FuturesUnordered, StreamExt};
use futures::TryStreamExt;
use rand::prelude::*;
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::Semaphore;
use tokio::task::JoinHandle;
use tokio::{task, time};

fn candidates() -> Vec<i32> {
    Vec::from([2, 2])
}

async fn produce_event(nanos: u64) -> i32 {
    println!("waiting {}", nanos);
    time::sleep(time::Duration::from_nanos(nanos)).await;
    1
}

async fn f(seconds: i64, semaphore: &Arc<Semaphore>) {
    let mut futures = vec![];
    for (i, j) in (0..1).enumerate() {
        for (i, event) in candidates().into_iter().enumerate() {
            let permit = Arc::clone(semaphore).acquire_owned().await;
            let secs = 500;
            futures.push(task::spawn(async move {
                let _permit = permit;
                produce_event(500); // 2nd example has an .await here
                println!("Event produced at {}", seconds);
            }));
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main()]
async fn main() {
    let semaphore = Arc::new(Semaphore::new(45000));
    for _ in 0..1 {
        let mut futures: FuturesUnordered<_> = (0..2).map(|moment| f(moment, &semaphore)).collect();
        while let Some(item) = futures.next().await {
            let () = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code instead of linking it externally, otherwise this question doesn't have much value for the other people in the future

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595857/what-is-the-difference-between-tokiospawnmy-future-await-and-just-my-future

Comment: The quick answer is: `JoinHandle` only represents the action of *waiting for the task to finish*.  The actual task already got started in the background and is not connected to whether or not you await the `JoinHandle`. Further, this allows `tokio` to move the spawned task to a different thread. If you only `.await` a task directly, this gets done in the same thread. Both have their valid usecases. Use normal `.await` whenever possible unless you have a reason to perform a `spawn`.

Comment: Ok after reading your linked code I think there are several effects mixed up: In your first example, none of the `produce_event` get executed because you don't await them. So it directly prints `Event produced`. In your second example, however, you actually do execute the `produce_event`s. Those go to sleep, and because you never wait for those to actually finish, the `main` function exits and cancels all the `produce_event`s. If you add a `wait` in your main, they get executed: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c1a59eb16933244f4e7f567cf0a9c8f6

Comment: Further, I don't understand your `futures` list, you push all the `JoinHandle`s into it but never do anything with it. Here, if you prevent that `main` exits too early by waiting for the `JoinHandle`s, you also see the messages: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f1d11d2c37ea6405ae492ad411bd2757

Comment: @Finomnis I mentioned at the end that if I do `.await` on every future in `futures` I get the predicted output. I understand now why the first example behaves as it does (all the async block gets executed in another task and in that task, I do not await the `produce_event` which causes the 1st print not to happen).
Now the second example is the one that gives me head aches.

Comment: Did you read my previous message? "Ok after reading ..."; I try to explain exactly that, why your second example behaves the way it does.

Comment: I read it, but I still do not understand why the 2nd print does not show

Comment: Because **main exits** and all the tasks get cancelled because they are still inside of the `sleep`. The second `print` gets executed **after** `produce_event` is finished, because you await it. `produce_event` never finishes, because `main` exits before that.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Makes sense now. I had to read also the comment answer from @Masklinn

Comment: No problem :) sometimes it's hard to see the easy reasons if you looked at it for too long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between tokio::spawn(my\_future).await and just my\_future.await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595857/what-is-the-difference-between-tokiospawnmy-future-await-and-just-my-future)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I tried a more complex example and it is a little unclear why I get a message printed by the 2nd print in this example because `task::spawn` gives me a `JoinHanlde` on which I do not do any `.await`.

You're spawning tasks. A task is a separate thread of execution which can execute concurrently to the current task, and can be scheduled in parallel.

All the `JoinHandle` does there is wait for that task to *end*, it doesn't control the task *running*.

> Meanwhile, I tried the same example, but with an await above the 2nd print, and now I get printed only the message in the 1st print.

You spawn a bunch of tasks and make them sleep. Since you don't wait for them to terminate (don't `join` them) nor is there any sort of sleep in their parent task, once all the tasks have been spawned the loops terminate, you reach the end of the `main` function and the program terminates.

At this point all the tasks are still sleeping.